# Loopback 4 jwt auth

Tags: typescript, rest, backend, loopback, loopback4

I followed the tutorial on lb4's website but I find it hard to follow. Now I've ran into a problem I can't seem to fix.

I've tried to compare with example shop but it has roles, securityID and uses email for login. I just want to use username and password for login. No roles, no securityID (I didnt really understand what it does)

Here is my error :
[image: Error]

Incompatibles types for UserProfile, I've looked into it but can't seem to find the problem. The screenshot is from application.ts

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you fixed this ?

Comment: I took code from the github and not the tutorial and it worked @Althaf M